# Magento same order mail sending for admin and customer

Tags: magento-1.9

When a new order is placed, the same mail copy is sending to both admin and the customer. I tried with different mail templates in the admin panel

Comment: Hi, do you mean you will not getting emails or unable to set changed email template?

Comment: @Meetanshi Both the mail content for admin and customer are same even when i changed the mail templates

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug, this is feature. if you want to change configuration, you can do it by  : **System > Configuration > Sales > Sales Emails > Order**

[image]

Comment: I changed the options. But it is not working

Comment: @sujivasagam can you tell what exactly you want ? means dont you want sending emails to admin ?

Comment: I want different mail content for admin and the customer not the same copy for both of them

Comment: @sujivasagam by default thats how it works,  mail content for admin and customer will be the same....

Comment: Actually i added different templates for admin and customer mail copies. But still receiving the same mail copy

Comment: @sujivasagam this link may help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10103074/can-magento-send-email-to-admin-when-user-place-order

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a different email content to admin, then you will need to use a custom module.

Please have a look at [this module](https://github.com/ajzele/Inchoo_AdminOrderNotifier).

I have used it for one of my clients and it works fine.

Alternatively, you can override Magento Sales module functionality and create a second template and send it to admin.